# My clients name isn't shown in Whois

Tags: domain-registration, godaddy, whois, gdpr, 1and1

My client's name isn't shown in whois

https://whois.icann.org/

nor

https://ae.godaddy.com/whois

nor any otheer whois service though I didn't make the domain private, the name, the address, and the phone number are hidden, and he wants to make them visible.

He has two domains, one from Godaddy and the other is from 1and1, he's living in Asia so GDPR shouldn't apply to him.

Did registrars add privacy automatically after GDPR? Last year all his details were visible on whois, today everything is hidden.

Comment: "nor any otheer whois service" - presumably you are seeing the _same_ details (although protected) regardless of which WHOIS service you use?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, I tried 3 different services, the ones mentioned above and https://www.whois.net, nothing works

Comment: None of the two whois servers you quote are relevant. IANA's one certainly not since it list only TLD data and as for GoDAddy ones it depends if your domain was registered with GoDaddy or not and even if it is you should always instead start with the **registry** whois server. Which depends on the TLD; something you are not telling what it is. Many registrars now just filter everything out in fear of GDPR (which can apply if the registrar or the owner is in Europe).

Comment: Do not use any of those whois services, at least by default. Use the registry whois server/service. This depends on the TLD, which you are not stating. Effects of the GDPR also depend on the TLD, and the nationality of the contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did registrars add privacy automatically after GDPR?

Yes, many did. However, you should be able to opt-out if you wish. You'll need to contact your domain registrar.